# How to get the correct redirect URL in java or Android?

Tags: java, android

For example, this url:
http://f.youku.com/player/getFlvPath/sid/137619797659700_01/st/mp4/fileid/0300200100503C2912CACF06F7B7BE321D4B39-09C7-D266-1DC7-72FBD749E129?K=d69a130f56086ce92828d4e4&hd=0&ts=26
When I copy this URL in Firefox and go, it will change to

```
http://117.27.153.211/youku/6971F2C094C4578E17DBE318A/0300200100503C2912CACF06F7B7BE321D4B39-09C7-D266-1DC7-72FBD749E129.mp4
```

In my project, I would to like get the second link in String for further use.
How to get this redirected URL??

Comment: what do you want to do please clarify

Comment: just GET/POST request the url you have, you will get the correct response even if the url has redirection

Comment: i just want to get the xxxx.mp4 <-- this link.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the redirected Url

```
final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
System.out.println(urlConnection.getURL().getHost());
```

the last line prints redirected url of the  your given as url